# Simulation study - what error variances to use from empirical data? MS error of an ANOVA or the variance of their residuals?

Tags: anova, variance, simulation, residuals, error

I want to do a simulation study in R and I have already some empirical data, that gives me a hint about the variance parameters to set. But what should I use for the error variance?
Here's an example of what I mean:

```
> a <- aov(terms(yield ~ block + N * P + K, keep.order=TRUE), npk)
> anova(a)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: yield
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
block      5 343.29  68.659  4.3911 0.012954 * 
N          1 189.28 189.282 12.1055 0.003684 **
P          1   8.40   8.402  0.5373 0.475637   
N:P        1  21.28  21.282  1.3611 0.262841   
K          1  95.20  95.202  6.0886 0.027114 * 
Residuals 14 218.90  15.636                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> var(residuals(a))
[1] 9.517536
```

So would I use 15.6 or 9.5 as my empirical error variance?

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) Begin with simple one-way ANOVA where details may be simpler. You can simulate the design with known $\sigma^2,$ several times, and see what best estimates that known value. (2) Think carefully about your more complex design, MS(Resid) has DF(Resid), far fewer than total nr $T$ of obs because several other params est'd. Nr of Residuals  is also $T,$ so `var(residuals(a))` must have donom $T-1.$ Resids can't be indep. obs because constrained to add to $1.$ Which is unbiased for $\sigma^2?$ Look at your 'a': Does it give you "residual std error"? Is square of that MS(Resid)?

Answer (score 0):

"Halfway" between the two suggestions of my (long, possibly cryptic) Comment,
here is a simulated two-way ANOVA, in which MS(Resid) is a reasonably good
estimate of the $\sigma^2$ used to simulate the model.

```
set.seed(1234)
e = rnorm(24, 0, 2)
sd(e)
[1] 1.87691

a = rep(1:2, each=12)
b = rep(rep(1:3, each=4), 2)
x = 2*a + 3*b + e
A = as.factor(a); B = as.factor(b)

out = aov(x~A+B); out
Call:
   aov(formula = x ~ A + B)

Terms:
                        A         B Residuals
Sum of Squares   49.67123 132.10586  73.73120
Deg. of Freedom         1         2        20

Residual standard error: 1.920042                  # compare 1.87691
Estimated effects may be unbalanced

anova(out)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
A          1  49.671  49.671  13.474  0.001517 ** 
B          2 132.106  66.053  17.917 3.478e-05 ***
Residuals 20  73.731   3.687                       # compare 1.92^2 = 3.6864                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Summary: $\sigma^2 = 2^2 = 4.$ The sample SD of simulated errors is 1.88,
Resid SE = 1.92, MS(Resid) = 3.69.

95% CI for $\sigma^2$ based on simulated `e` of my model is $(2.13, 6.93),$
which includes $\sigma^2 = 4.$

```
23*var(e)/qchisq(c(.975,.025), 23)
[1] 2.127980 6.931925
```

95% CI for $\sigma^2$ based on SS(Resid) is $(2.16, 7.69),$ which covers $\sigma^2=4.$

```
73.731/qchisq(c(.975,.025), 20)
[1] 2.157795 7.687698
```

*Note:* Here is information about the 24 residuals.

```
r = residuals(out)
length(r); mean(r); var(r)
[1] 24
[1] -1.168002e-16
[1] 3.205704
```

Answer (score 0):

Summing up what BruceET inspired me to, I found a rather simple answer to my question:

**Simulate with parameters that were received in the same way than you analyze later the simulated data.**

This is actually self explanatory and I could have found it out earlier but maybe somebody will have the same question one day.

This means: If you analyze empirical values with a linear model (e.g. ANOVA) and you then use the results as your parameters for your simulations (e.g. the residual MS for the error variance), make sure you also analyze the simulated data in the same way, i.e. analyze it with an ANOVA and look at the residual MS in this example.